# AJAX submitting form without refresh, not working properly

Tags: php, html, ajax

When I press "login" the script will run and print out "fill in all fields" (which is great) but it seems to echo it on the screen, then refresh the page.

AJAX:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
      var login = $("#login").val();
      $(".formMessage").load("inc/accounts.php",{
        username: username,
        password: password,
        login: login
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Form (only form on the page)

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="login">Login</button></div>
        <p class='formMessage'></p>
        <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
        <a href="register" class="forgot">Don't have an account?</a>
    </form>
```

PHP code (accounts.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $date = date("d/m/Y");
    $time = date("h:i a");

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
      echo "<span style='color: red;'>Fill in all fields!</span>";
    }elseif(!DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))){
      echo "<span style='color: red;'>Incorrect password/username!</span>";
    }elseif(!password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['password'])){
      echo "<span style='color: red;'>Incorrect password/username!</span>";
    }else{
      $uid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];

      $cstrong = True;
      $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
      DB::query('INSERT INTO logintokens VALUES(\'\', :token, :uid)', array(':token'=>sha1($token), ':uid'=>$uid));
      setcookie("uid", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 5, '/', '.link.com');
      setcookie("uid_", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', '.link.com');

      echo "<span style='color: green;'>Successfully logged in!</span>";
      echo '<script>window.location.href = "home";</script>';
    }
  }
```

Video to show what happens: https://gyazo.com/8233450b6493bfe415105ea5dbb61b28

Comment: put `event.preventDefault()` before `$("form").submit(function(event){` ends

Comment: Or `return false;` at the end.

Comment: @ZainFarooq how did I miss that?? Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar No. You can place it at the start too

Comment: @ZainFarooq I missed the last word of your sentence, I thought you were saying to put it on the line before the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed `event.preventDefault()` which stops the default action of an element from happening. Your final code should look like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(event){
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var login = $("#login").val();
  $(".formMessage").load("inc/accounts.php",{
    username: username,
    password: password,
    login: login
  });
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

For more info you can visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Couple of suggestions for this

- Give your form an id so you can reference it using `$('#formid')`, just for readability.
- In your listener for form submit, the prevent the default action.

Here is an example of how to do that, you are already passing in the event in your code so we just need to prevent its default action (submitting + refreshing).

```
...
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
...
```